# PYTHON NO HAY COINCIDENCIA EN EL DESEMPAQUETADO

Tags: python, sqlite, decoradores

recien estoy incursionando en el tema decoradores, y altratar de utilizarlo con la sentecia select(sqlite3) me dice que solo consigue un argumento y en realidad es lo que quiero pasarle solo un argumento no se porque aqui me pide otro...

```
def ejecutar(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        resultado = None
        conexion = sqlite3.connect('escuela.db')
        cursor = conexion.cursor()

        if func.__name__ == 'mostrar':
            sentencia, _ = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cursor.execute(sentencia)
            resultado = cursor.fetchone()
            return resultado
        else:
            sentencia, valor = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cursor.execute(sentencia, valor)
            conexion.commit() 

        
        cursor.close()
        conexion.close()    
        
    return inner 


@ejecutar
def mostrar(columnas='', tabla='', condicion=''): 
        #lista_sel = (valor, )
        if condicion:
            orden = f'SELECT {columnas} FROM {tabla} WHERE {condicion}'
            print(orden)
            return orden
        else:
            orden = f'SELECT {columnas} FROM {tabla}'
            print(orden)
            return (orden,)

mostrar(columnas='nombre', tabla='preceptores', condicion='')
```

Salida por consola:

```
File "/home/mag/Plantillas/proyecto/git-aula/prueba.py", line 309, in inner
    sentencia, _ = func(*args, **kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Lo que alega es que la función retorna sólo un valor, pero tú esperas dos: `sentencia` y `_`. En `mostrar` tienes dos `return`: uno con un argumento, otro con un argumento + None.

Comment: La sugerencia es dejar ambos `return orden` (un argumento) y reducir a `sentencia = func(*args, **kwargs)`. Claramente no necesitas el segundo argumento, dado que lo descartas de inmediato.

Comment: dio resultado!!! ..gracias